# View .docx file on Github and use git diff on .docx file format

Tags: git, github

I have two questions:

1. Is there any way to view a `.docx` file on `Github`? We have uploaded all of our assignments onto Github, but there is no way we can view it within the browser. It would be nice if we could view those `.docx` files in the browser without downloading the file.
2. How can I use `git diff` on the `.docx` file format? I tried to use `catdoc` but it didn't work for me. I think I have used `git diff` on Windows for the `.doc` format before, but it's not working for me on Mac.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `catdoc` only works for `.doc` files.

Comment: [Word Diff](http://ben.balter.com/2015/02/06/word-diff/) could also help here

Answer (score 19):

2. Answer for second part of question.
   Already an old post but popping up in top 10 without an answer.
   With the following settings you get a poor man's diff on docx files.

In .gitattributes use:

```
*.docx diff=zip
```

In .git/config use:

```
[diff "zip"]
      textconv = unzip -c -a
```

As a bonus my settings for old word/excel and new word/excel:

In .gitattributes use:

```
*.doc diff=word
*.xsl diff=excel
*.xlsx diff=zip
*.docx diff=zip
```

In .git/config use:

```
[diff "word"] 
    textconv = strings
[diff "excel"]
    textconv = strings
[diff "zip"]
    textconv = unzip -c -a
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Unfortunately the XML diff is quite messy so I've been using "  textconv = docx2txt <" instead, which gives a diff of just the text, making it a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 16):

Answering your second question -

Usually when you try

```
git diff filename.docx
```

you will get output of the form -

> Binary files a/filename.docx and b/filename.docx differ

Not very helpful. A perfect way around that is to use [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/installing.html).

- Install Pandoc from above link on your system.
- Create or edit file ~/.gitconfig (linux, Mac) or "c:\Documents and Settings\user.gitconfig" (Windows) to add (or use `git config --global --edit`)

  ```
  [diff "pandoc"]
       textconv=pandoc --to=markdown
       prompt = false
  [alias]
       wdiff = diff --word-diff=color --unified=1`
  ```
- In your git controlled directory with .docx files, create or edit file .gitattributes (linux, Windows and Mac) to add

  ```
  *.docx diff=pandoc
  ```
- You can commit **.gitattributes** so that it stays for use in other computers, but you'll need to edit ~/.gitconfig in every new computer you want to use.
- Now you can see a pretty coloured diff with the changes you have made to your .docx file since the last commit

  ```
   git wdiff file.docx
  ```

More details can be found [here](https://github.com/vigente/gerardus/wiki/Integrate-git-diffs-with-word-docx-files).

Answer (score 8):

The accepted solution (using strings / unzip ) didn't work very well for me on Linux Mint 19.3. The following seems to work pretty well for most doc/docx/rtf/xls files as well as their LibreOffice counterparts. Some of these might work on Windows via cygwin/git bash but I have not tested; if the packages I mention are not available in cygwin/git bash, then I would look for python/perl scripts that do the same conversion and substitute with those instead.

1. Install prerequisites: `sudo apt install git pandoc catdoc odt2txt`.
2. Note that catdoc and odt2txt include multiple tools for handling doc/xls/ppt/odt/ods/odp formats not just the ones in the package name. Likewise, pandoc handles all of the newer zipped 'x' formats.
3. I wanted my attributes to apply as [Global (e.g. User-scoped)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28026767/where-should-i-place-my-global-gitattributes-file) rather than per-project as done in the other answers. To create User-scoped git attributes file, use `mkdir ~/.config/git/ && touch ~/.config/git/attributes` (on Windows this should be `mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\.config\git" && echo "" > "%USERPROFILE%\.config\git\attributes"`)
4. Setup git attributes file (either the user-scoped file mentioned in the previous step or the project-scoped file `${projectDir}/.git/info/attributes` as desired):

```
    # handle windows *.reg files (utf-16 which git doesn't normally like)
    *.reg diff=utf16

    # handle misc common document formats
    *.pdf diff=pdf
    *.rtf diff=catdoc

    # handle libre/open document formats
    *.ods diff=ods2txt
    *.odp diff=odp2txt
    *.odt diff=odt2txt

    # handle older common ms document formats
    # note: ppt did not work for me
    *.doc diff=catdoc
    *.ppt diff=catppt
    *.xls diff=xls2csv

    # handle newer zipped ms document formats
    # note: pptx and xlsx did not work for me
    *.docx diff=pandoc
    *.pptx diff=pandoc
    *.xlsx diff=pandoc
```

5. Create .gitconfig definitions (either in the user-scoped `~/.gitconfig` or in the project-scoped `${projectDir}/.git/config`). Much of this is based on [this article](https://medium.com/@mbrehin/git-advanced-diff-odt-pdf-doc-xls-ppt-25afbf4f1105) but altered based on my own testing.

```
[core]
        autocrlf = false
    [diff]
        guitool = kdiff3
    [diff "odp2txt"]
        textconv = odp2txt
        binary = true
    [diff "odt2txt"]
        textconv = odt2txt
        binary = true
    [diff "ods2txt"]
        textconv = ods2txt
        binary = true
    [diff "catdoc"]
        textconv = catdoc
        binary = true
    # note catppt did not work for me
    [diff "catppt"]
        textconv = catppt
        binary = true
    [diff "xls2csv"]
        textconv = xls2csv
        binary = true
    [diff "xlsx2csv"]
        textconv = xlsx2csv
        binary = true
    [diff "pandoc"]
        textconv=pandoc --to=markdown
        prompt = false
    [diff "pdf2txt"]
        textconv=pdf2txt
        binary = true
    [diff "utf16"]
        textconv = iconv -c -f UTF-16LE -t ASCII
```

I was never able to successfully get diffs working for xlsx, ppt, or pptx even after downloading the latest version of pandoc from [their github page](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases). The docx conversion worked fine even with the super old version that is in the Mint/Ubuntu/Debian repos (v1.19.2.4 from 2016). For the xlsx/pptx samples I was using, I always got either "Invalid UTF-8 stream fatal" (old version) or "UTF-8 decoding error" (new version).

This could have been due to the sample files I was using (some samples from the web and some samples I created by converting LibreOffice documents), my system setup, the versions I was using or something else.

For completeness, after installing the newer pandoc, I was using:

```
$ uname -vipor
5.3.0-40-generic #32~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 3 14:05:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ dpkg -l catdoc odt2txt pandoc git xlsx2csv|grep '^ii'
ii  catdoc         1:0.95-4.1          amd64        text extractor for MS-Office files
ii  git            1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.5 amd64        fast, scalable, distributed revision control system
ii  odt2txt        0.5-1build2         amd64        simple converter from OpenDocument Text to plain text
ii  pandoc         2.9.2-1             amd64        general markup converter
ii  xlsx2csv       0.20+20161027+git5785081-1 all          convert xslx files to csv format
```

EDIT: Also tried using the package `xlsx2csv` for xlsx conversion instead of pandoc and I had issues with that as well. Could be something to do with my samples but since I am not really doing anything special to create them I would consider that a coverage-gap / limitation of xlsx2csv/pandoc if so.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there any way to view a .docx file on Github?

Not yet (Q4 2016) unless the Word document is pure text.

> How can I use git diff on the .docx file format?

Since git for Windows 1.9.5, and the [**Git for Windows 2.5.3**](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.5.3.windows.1) (Sept. 2015, and [issue 355](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/355)), you don't have to do any custom settings:

```
git diff -- myWord.docx
```

That will work. (It does for `.doc` and `.pdf` too)

And since [Git for Windows 2.10.1](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.10.1.windows.1), you can diff `.docm` and `.dotm` too (see [PR 128](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/pull/128)).

---

[jifb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12227050/jifb) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22439517/view-docx-file-on-github-and-use-git-diff-on-docx-file-format/39895115?noredirect=1#comment131178285_39895115):

> The `docx` etc. support is based on file conversion executable `odt2txt`, `antiword`, `docx2txt`(`.pl`) and `pdftotext` which are invoked (configured in system-wide `gitattributes` and `gitconfig`).
>
> `rtf` files are not converted (simple "`cat`" in Git for Windows 2.28.0) but unconverted `rtf` is well comparable if produced by "old" programs like Wordpad/Ted.

Comment: Just to add: The docx etc. support is based on file conversion executables odt2txt, antiword, docx2txt(.pl) and pdftotext which are invoked (configured in system-wide gitattributes and gitconfig). rtf files are not converted (simple "cat" in git for Windows 2.28.0) but unconverted rtf is well comparable if produced by "old" programs like Wordpad/Ted.

Comment: @jifb Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 3):

After half-heartedly circling around Stackoverflow and Google for years, I just found out today that the official git book has a [walkthrough](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes).

1. Install [`docx2txt`](http://docx2txt.sourceforge.net/). On Ubuntu 16.04, I just used the official repositories:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install docx2txt
   ```
2. Write a wrapper script (`docx2txt` requires some arguments.) as follows:

   ```
   #! /usr/bin/env bash
   docx2txt "$1" -
   ```
3. I called the script `d2t`, so I added that to a folder somewhere in my `$PATH`. Remember to make it executable so that git can run it.

   ```
   chmod +x d2t
   mv d2t /somewhere/in/your/PATH
   ```
4. Now make your repository aware of this by adding this block to `.git/config`:

   ```
   [diff "word"]
       textconv = d2t
   ```

   *Note: the [book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes) suggests a command instead, which I assume you can use with the `--global` flag as well to apply this filter to all repos should you so wish:

   ```
   git config --global diff.word.textconv d2t
   ```
5. For the repository where you want this to work, edit `.gitattributes`:

   ```
   *.docx diff=word
   ```
6. Now you should be able to `git diff` your docx documents.

   ```
   diff --git a/goodpoint.docx b/goodpoint.docx
   index 0d6e78c..4476023 100644
   --- a/goodpoint.docx
   +++ b/goodpoint.docx
   @@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
    Making many good points

     1. Overview
   -- 2l3k23lk
   +- this is a test
    - 23lkjl2k3j

     2. Remarks
   ```

Edit: tried this on git 2.7.4. you can't `checkout` and `add` in patches without doing more work.

Comment: What next, .xlsx, .pptx?! I think another approach will benefit well from https://stackoverflow.com/a/32712206/

Comment: This works for me, but with a couple changes. For step #1 I used `pip install docx2txt`. Instead of steps #2, 3, and 4, the `d2t` thing didn't work. Instead, I just needed to run the command `git config --global diff.word.textconv docx2txt`. Steps 5 and 6 work fine. I'm using git version 2.30.0, pip 21.0.1, which ended up installing docx2txt 0.8.

Answer (score 1):

This is problematic and according to the best of my knowledge, not possible on github or any other git host for that matter. While git can be used to version anything, things like git diff will return differences in two versions in plain text form. Illegible.

I feel that this is not without a reason though. There are unlimited file formats in the world and many of them are proprietary. Thus, in place of supporting every single format like VLC, git uses text files for everything.

Also even if git did somehow support docx, it wouldn't be able to display formatting changes inside the terminal, let alone cmd. If it's just text, better store it as a text file. Or manually checkout a previous version to compare the changes.

Comment: `.docx` , `.xmlx` etc files are binary files. So git just shows it's binary form.  However they are also zip files. So open / extract them you gonna get bunch of mostly `.xml` files that can be " `git diff` ed".   So even themes etc can be compared for changes.

Answer (score 1):

A `.docx` file is actually a zip (you can change the file type and poke around inside).  If the `.docx` was treated as a directory then inside the main file is stored as an XML style file and it's text, not binary.

Sad thing is that there are no carriage returns. Otherwise doing a text diff on the 'document.xml' file inside the directory would be really useful.  As an XML file line breaks in the file would not affect the content so they could be added.